# Assign null check to reused const in upper scope of function without non-null assertion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Take this code snippet example:

```js
const [interval, setInterval] = useState<PartialInterval | null>(null);

const handleDaySelect = (day: DateData) => {
  const isStartSelected = interval?.start;
  const isEndSelected = interval?.end;

  if (!isStartSelected) {
    setInterval({ start: parseDayToDate(day.dateString) });
    return;
  }

  if (isStartSelected && !isEndSelected) {
    const isSelectedEndBeforeSelectedStart = isBefore(
      parseDayToDate(day.dateString),
      interval.start!,
    );
    
    if (isSelectedEndBeforeSelectedStart) {
      setInterval({
        start: parseDayToDate(day.dateString),
        end: interval.start,
      });
      return;
    }

    setInterval({ ...interval, end: parseDayToDate(day.dateString) });
    return;
  }

  if (isStartSelected && isEndSelected) {
    setInterval({ start: parseDayToDate(day.dateString) });
  }
};
```

Where the null checks for the `interval` are assigned as a const value at the beginning of the function. In this case, I want to use `no-non-null-assertion` so I don't have to write each declaration like so `interval.start!` is this actually achievable in typescript without explicitly doing the check at each if statement? `if(interval?.start)` and can continue to use the already defined check of `isStartSelected`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, why dont you make an check at the top of your function `if(interval === null) return`, now `interval` will always be truthy

Comment: I dont know if its an good idea to use `setInterval`, wich is already available, as an function name

Comment: Typescript still complains that the value `interval.start` is undefined later down the line when used, so that doesn't work unfortunately. Second answer, it doesn't matter that we are using setInterval as the definition isn't tied to the available function, it's tied to the `useState`

Answer (score 0):

A handy way will be to use [assertive functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) to assert and handle the `interval` is not nullish and upon successful assertion it returns the `interval` object.

Typescript will never complain about its being null because it is returned from the function.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer here:

Use the assigned const variable you've given at the top of the scope.

So instead of writing the variable `isStartSelected` and using it as a bool check for undefined, you can assign the variable a better name `startInterval` and then `ts` will let you use the variable you've assigned as an undefined check as well as able to parse and use it later in the function.

Simple case of overcomplicating the problem